# Error raised in model.fit() if validation_data ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: keras, tensorflow, nlp, numpy, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a simple autoencoder model. I'm reading training data from a csv which consists of word embeddings. I have this code, but the error in the title is raised in `model.fit()`  function and connected with my `validation data`. I tried many things however the error remained. I'm new in NLP and maybe my logic is totally wrong I don't know. So, I'd be appreciated if anybody can help. Here is my code:

```
def train_predict(df):
X_train, X_validation = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
X = X_train.iloc[:, :-1].to_numpy()           #shape is (1880,220) in here
X = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)                #shape is (1880,220,1)
X_val = X_validation.iloc[:,:-1].to_numpy()   #shape is (300,220)
X_val= tf.expand_dims(X_val, axis=-1)         #shape is (300,220,1)

inputs, decoder_output, visualization = autoEncoder(X)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=decoder_output)
encoder_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=visualization)

batch_size = 128
train_steps = len(X) // batch_size
val_steps = len(X_val) // batch_size
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_data=X_val, validation_steps=val_steps,epochs=100) 
result = model.evaluate(X_val, steps=10)
```

Also the detail of my autoEncoder function code is as follows:

```
def autoEncoder(X_train):
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],1))
# parameters
conv_1 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
max_pool_1 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(conv_1)

conv_2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(max_pool_1)
max_pool_2 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(conv_2)

# BOTTLE NECK

bottle_neck = Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(max_pool_2)
visualization = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(bottle_neck)

# DECODER
conv_3 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(bottle_neck)
upsample_1 = UpSampling1D(size=2)(conv_3)

conv_4 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upsample_1)
upsample_2 = UpSampling1D(size=2)(conv_4)

decoder_output = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(upsample_2)

return inputs, decoder_output, visualization
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'd be excellent if you could copy-paste the entire stack of error that your code produces, something that everyone should follow for error-related questions because that makes debugging that much easier.

Here's an attempt to reproduce the same error using a dummy dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(11)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

def autoEncoder(X_train):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1))
    conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    max_pool_1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(conv_1)

    conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(max_pool_1)
    max_pool_2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(conv_2)

    bottle_neck = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(max_pool_2)
    visualization = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(bottle_neck)

    conv_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(bottle_neck)
    upsample_1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(size=2)(conv_3)

    conv_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(upsample_1)
    upsample_2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(size=2)(conv_4)

    decoder_output = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(upsample_2)

    return inputs, decoder_output, visualization

X = np.random.randn(1880, 220)
X_val = np.random.randn(300, 220)

X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)
X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)   # (1880, 220, 1)
X_val = np.expand_dims(X_val, axis=-1)
X_val = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_val)  # (300, 220, 1)

inputs, decoder_output, visualization = autoEncoder(X)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=decoder_output)
encoder_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=visualization)

batch_size = 128
train_steps = len(X) // batch_size
val_steps = len(X_val) // batch_size
model.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_data = X_val, validation_steps=val_steps, epochs=100)
```

On google-colab this gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-a889c5a46f35> in <module>()
      3 val_steps = len(X_val) // batch_size
      4 model.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], loss='mean_squared_error')
----> 5 model.fit(X, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_data = X_val, validation_steps=val_steps, epochs=100)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1041               (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
   1042 
-> 1043     if validation_data:
   1044       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight = (
   1045           data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __bool__(self)
    990 
    991   def __bool__(self):
--> 992     return bool(self._numpy())
    993 
    994   __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

which is identical to your OP. The reason it'd be better to post the error stack is because the answer is hidden in these lines, specifically:

```
1043     if validation_data:
1044       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight = (
1045           data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))
```

The format of `validation_data` is identical to `(x, y, sample_weight)`. Here's what [fit method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) documentation has to say:

> `validation_data` will override `validation_split`. `validation_data` could be: - tuple `(x_val, y_val)` of Numpy arrays or tensors - tuple `(x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)` of Numpy arrays - dataset For the first two cases, batch_size must be provided. For the last case, `validation_steps` could be provided.

I think you now understand why you're getting an error, there's no `Y` for the your autoencoder. Which shouldn't be of any concern since your `X` itself is your `Y`. Here's a line from [an encoder tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder#:%7E:text=Train%20the%20model%20using%20x_train,to%20reconstruct%20the%20original%20images.%20.&text=Now%20that%20the%20model%20is,images%20from%20the%20test%20set.) that would help us in this situation:

> Train the model using `x_train` as both the input and the target. The `encoder` will learn to compress the dataset from 784 dimensions to the latent space, and the `decoder` will learn to reconstruct the original images.

So, what you were expected to do is to write the following:

```
model.fit(X, X, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_data=(X_val, X_val), validation_steps=val_steps, epochs=100)
```

which indeed starts the training!

Comment: This is the exact same error. Sorry, I thought the explaining will do it and nobody would need the entire stack of errors. Thank you for your explanation :)

Comment: I still get the error!