# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). Keras attribute error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to execute the following code :( this code is used to train the model. But i've been getting this error and im searchin for a day and still got no answer to solve this Please help

this is the code I tried to execute

```
print("Starting Trainning Model", date_time(1))


steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator)
validation_steps=len(validation_generator)



optimizer=optimizers.Adam()
loss='categorical_crossentropy'
metrics=['accuracy']
epochs = 100


model.compile(optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_steps, 
    class_weight=class_weight)

print("Completed Model Trainning", date_time(1))
```

This is the error i get.

```
Starting Trainning Model Timestamp: 2021-05-23 10:49:40
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-a066d8eb22ce> in <module>()
     23     validation_data=validation_generator,
     24     validation_steps=validation_steps,
---> 25     class_weight=class_weight)
     26 
     27 print("Completed Model Trainning", date_time(1))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model)
   1114     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()
   1115     dataset = self._adapter.get_dataset()
-> 1116     if class_weight:
   1117       dataset = dataset.map(_make_class_weight_map_fn(class_weight))
   1118     self._inferred_steps = self._infer_steps(steps_per_epoch, dataset)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What am i doing wrong help me out.

Comment: as I remember `class_weight` should be a Dictionary mapping from indices to weights , current me if im wrong

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66767761/14290681) answer your query? Else, can you share complete code and traceback? which makes debugging much easier. Thanks!